# Aurelia custom element with dynamic content

Tags: aurelia

I have a a lot of object instances in an array of my model that all conform to an interface ITrack and I wanted to create a paginate component for these as a learning exercise.
I wanted to create a component that would allow me to write this in a template

```
<pager page-size="10" model.bind="tracks">
<div>
<span>{% track.name %}</span>
</div>
</pager>
```

So a pager would be created and each ITrack displayed would have to format

```
<div>
<span>{% track.name %}</span>
</div>
```

Is it possible for the component to grab the content between the pager element to use as a template when creating the list of tracks.

I have looked at http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/creating-components/3
but not sure if I could get the content.

Or is this not a good approach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Create a custom element with a template part.

**pagerCustomElement.html**

```
<template>
  <div repeat.for="item of selectedItems" part="item-template">
    ${item}
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.html**

```
<require from="./pagerCustomElement"></require>
<pager items.bind="tracks">
  <template replace-part="item-template">
    <div>${item.title}</div>
  </template>
</pager>
```

See the full example here: https://gist.run/?id=698ba0c7cf73f1f55b1a770182da41c4

The "documentation" for this can be found in [this issue](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/70).

Comment: if my answer blew your mind, show me some upvote and accept love